# Excel - Automatically insert current date/time into a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What I am trying to do is when I insert something into column `A` or `B` current date and time to be inserted/updated into column `D`. Of course I already done that but I want to exclude columns `C` and `D` which means when something is inserted in these columns date/time should not be inserted/updated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 Then Cells(Target.Row, "D") = Now()
End Sub
```

Also I have another code but still cannot find a way to exclude some columns (to make a range of columns which updating date/time should work)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target(1, 1).Row > 1 Then
        With Cells(Target(1, 1).Row, "D")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT: This is my final code.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Target.Row > 1) And (Target.Column = 1) Then
       With Cells(Target.Row, "D")
            .Value = Date
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
      End With
    End If

    If (Target.Row > 1) And (Target.Column = 2) Then
      With Cells(Target.Row, "E")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
      End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add condition for columns A and B to be fulfilled in addition to the row condition:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Row > 1) And ((Target.Column = 1) Or (Target.Column = 2)) Then
      'Cells(Target.Row, "D") = Now()
      With Cells(Target.Row, "D")
          .Value = Now
          .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
      End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the date will be inserted only when those two columns are edited.

Comment: With this approach is there a way to define the format as I did in my second approach (.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss") ?

Comment: @TWDbag Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

You must check:

1. The row is not 1
2. The column is 1 or 2
3. Target is single cell

and maybe

4. Column D in the current row is empty

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 _
   And Target.Column <= 2 _
   And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, "D") = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This code will NOT work while copypaste a range with more than 1 cell.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column
    If r > 1 And (c = 1 Or c = 2) Then
        If Cells(r, "C") = "" And Cells(r, "D") = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(r, "D") = Now()
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This should test all required conditions.